# Filter Ranking based on Noise

Tags: filters, filter-design, noise

I spent a good amount of my time searching but I can't seem to find any straightforward answer. I want to know the comparison/ranking of the filters (Butterworth, Chebyshev I, Chebyshev II, Elliptic) with regards to filtering out  noise (reduce noise power output). Which would have the least to best performance, and which one will use the most amount of filter coefficients to do so.

[EDIT] The signal would be theoretically a digitized Wi-Fi channel with noise generated from a random number generator.

Comment: None of your filter types make sense.

Comment: Perhaps see my old paper: E. Voigtman and J.D. Winefordner, *Low-pass filters for signal averaging*, Rev. Sci. Instrum., 57(5), 1986, 957-966. Maybe it will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as "rejection of noise"; it's a filter, it doesn't care nor can't know whether what it filters is noise or signal.

You can only compare these by making a statement on the *spectrum* of your noise, and how much of that spectrum makes it through the filter's frequency response. Also, it would very much makes sense to also compare your signal-of-interest's spectrum the same way - after all, what you care about (usually) is SNR, not just noise power (otherwise, the filter that just multiplies everything with 0 and lets nothing through is always the best, even though it completely erases the signal alongside the noise).

We don't know the noise you care about, nor the signal. So, you'll have to write down a noise model and a signal model; for example "White additive noise" for the noise, and "uncorrelated QAM symbols having gone through an RRC filter" for the signal would be such models.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. I am new and I thought the filters would have a general behavior regardless of signal and noise type. Sorry for that. I added additional info to my post.

Comment: yeah, so, bad news: Wifi is OFDM, which means its spectrum is practically flat, as your noise (probably – I'm assumiong your random number generator is white). So, no filter will improve your SNR in any way, unless it happens to be a synchronized OFDM receiver (which is in a way a filter bank). And your signal processing is digital, you definitely don't want analog filter types. So, nope, this is not the approach you're looking for, at all.

Comment: oh, that is unfortunate. Thanks for the reply, though. I will try to search for other ways.